# Image Location/Address in Excel File (Apache POI)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a requirement which reading question template and show the question at browser in my web application.
In Excel template, there might be `question/text` including with `image` as below picture. I can read `question/text` and `image`.
The problem is I cannot decide which `image` is related which `question` row. That's why, I need to know location(Row, Cell Address, etc...) of images.

Question Template

[image]

Expected display in Browser

[image]

In the template, the image only related with question No.1.
How can I know `image` cell address/location in excel file?